# Can I use HTTP instead of HTTPS to host MVC client to work with IdentityServer?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I had my quickstart programs working on my local test environment: A MVC client accessing an API through IdentityServer. And this is all setup using HTTPS and `self-host` (Kestrel). What I am wondering is - can I host MVC in HTTP instead of HTTPS when working with IdentityServer? It doesn't seem matter if I change all parties to use HTTP or just MVC and leave the rest with HTTPS, as soon as I changed my MVC from `https://localhost:5009` to `http://localhost:5008` (in several places), the app failed with an error `"invalid redirect uri"`.
Am I missing something, or is this simply something not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run over HTTP just fine during development, but in production you should always try to use HTTPS.

The error you get is because the RedirectURLs in the client definition in IdentityServer does not match the url of your client:

```
RedirectUris =
{
    "https://localhost:5001/...."
},
```

It is also recommended in the client to set this to false if you want to use HTTP when you define your OpenIDConnect options.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets if HTTPS is required for the metadata address or authority.
    /// The default is true. This should be disabled only in development environments.
    /// </summary>
    public bool RequireHttpsMetadata { get; set; } = true;
```

If you mange to get to the IdentityServer login page, then in the URL you will find the the redirectURL that is actually sent to IdentityServer. Or capture the request using fiddler to see what the requestUrl is that is passed to identityserver.

When I look at the screenshot, you have port 5009 in the allowedRedirectURis and 5008 in the request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tore. Did what you suggested but still no luck. My IdentityServer throws an error that says "Invalid redirect_url: http://localhost:6008/signin-oidc". But in my IdentityServer client configuration I have "RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:6008/signin-oidc" }". And in MVC I have: "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6008". (I even tried removing "/signin-oidc" from redirect url so both sides match exactly). I also set "                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;" in the ConfigureServices of my MVC Startup. The result is the same - same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a copy of your startup classes

Comment: There should be a "http://" in front of each urls in the comment posted above. Don't know whey the post hides them.

Comment: Tore, I have posted my Startup classes (both MVC and IdentityServer) as answer as they don't fix in Comment. Thanks again.

Comment: Tore, I never get to the login page. But the console windows show those urls and error messages. I have updated my last "anwser" post to included those screenshots. Thanks again!

Comment: added a new answer at the end of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too... what's wired about this is that I have no idea where this value is coming from - I searched the entire solution and I don't find a single 5009 anywhere! Besides, does the AllowedRedirctUris really matter, as the Redirect_uri value is correct?

Comment: My bad! I forgot that some of the settings are actually persisted in the DB as I am using EF model. Redirect_uri is one of them. So, even though I changed the value in the code, the persisted value still appears as "AllowedRedirctUris". Now I think I got passed this issue...into another one :) But thank you so much Tore for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my MVC Startup

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            // The default is true. This should be disabled only in development environments!!!
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5005";

            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code";

            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Scope.Add("profile"); 
            options.Scope.Add("email"); 
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true; 

            options.Scope.Add("MyAPI"); 
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access"); 
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
                .RequireAuthorization(); 
        });
    }
}
```

Here is Startup of IdentityServer

```
public class Startup
{
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        var connstr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyIDSConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connstr));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

            options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
        })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connstr,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connstr,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            });

        // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        //services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(
        //    new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "certs", "IdentityServer4Auth.pfx")));

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                // register your IdentityServer with Google at https://console.developers.google.com
                // enable the Google+ API
                // set the redirect URI to https://localhost:5001/signin-google
                options.ClientId = "";
                options.ClientSecret = "";
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }

        // uncomment if use MVC
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        // Add IdentityServer to the pipeline
        // UseIdentityServer includes a call to UseAuthentication, so it’s not necessary to have both
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        // uncomment if use MVC
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }

    private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            if (!context.Clients.Any())
            {
                foreach (var client in Config.Clients)
                {
                    context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
            {
                foreach (var resource in Config.IdentityResources)
                {
                    context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.ApiScopes.Any())
            {
                foreach (var resource in Config.ApiScopes)
                {
                    context.ApiScopes.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the IdentityServer console window when starts
[image]

And here is the MVC console window when start
[image]